# Not able to print file content on screen

Tags: c, file, printing, console

I need to copy the content of one file to another and print this another's file content on screen.

The program creates the file and copies the content with no problem but it does not print anything on screen.

Thanks for your time.

```
void organizeContent(FILE *file) {

  FILE *file_student = fopen("student.txt", "w+");

  int ch;
  while((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    fputc(ch, file_student);
  fflush(file_student);

  int ch2;
  while((ch2 = fgetc(file_student)) != EOF) {
    fputc(ch2, stdout);

  return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first `while` loop the `file_student` stream will be at the end of the file. `fclose` and `fopen` the file again or `rewind` it before reading it back.

Comment: Thank you!

As I don't have enough reputation here I can't upvote your comment but it was very helpful!